# WPS Office License agreement always showing when opening

Tags: 22.04, license, wps-office

Hello I am user Ubuntu 22.04

**Problem:** When I try open WPS Office it always show window **License agreement confirmation**. Not only when I click the WPS logo, even when I'm logged in it still appears even worse again when opening the file. This is bothers me a lot, and I hope your answer can help me.

**Note:** I've tried to fix it by reinstalling the package `sudo gdebi wps-office_11.1.0.10976.XA_amd64.deb` but this isn't work.

[image: WPS Office License agreement confirmation window]

Comment: To clarify: You read and accept it and in the next use it appears again?

Comment: Yes, more than one times.

Answer (score 0):

I just correct this behavior by removing the directory :
~/.config/Kingsoft